# Some sites ask you to download their AppStore app - how can I do this for my site?

Tags: javascript, html

Many sites wants you to download their app when you visit their webpage via mobile safari. Is this a safari browser feature? Or is this something I need to code.

How can I do it? What exactly this feature is called?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This feature is called Smart App Banner. It requires you to set a specific meta-tag on your website to link it to your App Store app, like so:

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=myAppStoreID, affiliate-data=myAffiliateData, app-argument=myURL">
```

You can find out more [in the documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html)